# NotSupportedException: System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager - Hololens 2 & OPC UA SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, hololens, opc-ua

I am trying to read the value of a node on Hololens 2 using the OPC UA protocol.

I am using OPC UA SDK for .NET (Opc.UaFx.Client 2.14.0). I connect to the server with the following code:

```
public bool ConnectToOpcUaMachine(string machineIp) {
    try {
        _client = new OpcClient(machineIp);
        _client.OperationTimeout = 2000;
        _client.Connect();
    } catch( System.Exception ex ) {
        Debug.Log("Couldn't connect to OPC server");
        Debug.LogException(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I call this method in the Editor I connect to the server successfully and can read the node value. However when I try and do the same thing on a Hololens 2 I get the following error:

```
NotSupportedException: System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager::CreateBufferManager
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager.CreateBufferManager (System.Int64 maxBufferPoolSize, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.Ua.Bindings.BufferManager..ctor (System.String name, System.Int32 maxPoolSize, System.Int32 maxBufferSize) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel.SaveSettings (System.Uri url, Opc.Ua.TransportChannelSettings settings) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel.Initialize (System.Uri url, Opc.Ua.TransportChannelSettings settings) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.Ua.WcfChannelBase.CreateUaBinaryChannel (Opc.Ua.ApplicationConfiguration configuration, Opc.Ua.EndpointDescription description, Opc.Ua.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, Opc.Ua.ServiceMessageContext messageContext) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.Ua.DiscoveryChannel.Create (System.Uri discoveryUrl, Opc.Ua.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, Opc.Ua.ServiceMessageContext messageContext) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.Ua.DiscoveryClient.Create (System.Uri discoveryUrl, Opc.Ua.EndpointConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at va..ctor (System.Uri a, Opc.UaFx.OpcApplicationConfiguration b) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.UaFx.Client.OpcDiscoveryClient..ctor (System.Uri discoveryUrl, Opc.UaFx.OpcApplicationConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.UaFx.Client.OpcClient.a (System.Uri a, Opc.UaFx.OpcApplicationConfiguration b) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.UaFx.Client.OpcClient.a () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.UaFx.Client.OpcClient.ConnectCore () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Opc.UaFx.Client.OpcClient.Connect () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at OpcUaClientScript.ConnectToOpcUaMachine (System.String machineIp) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at OpcUaClientScript.GetDebugVal () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1].Invoke (T1 handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ReleaseMouse (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, UnityEngine.GameObject currentOverGo) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMousePress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule+MouseButtonEventData data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMouseEvent (System.Int32 id) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

HoloLens app uses IL2CPP scripting back end for building projects and it has some inherent [scripting restrictions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html). Besides, I noticed that there is a closed issue that has feedback that the compatibility issue of OPC UA with Unity IL2CPP scripting backend, it is maybe helpful for you: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/760#issuecomment-514502763